# Knex migration seeding completes with foreign key error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm seeding my db from an array that looks like this (words and definitions are in a many to many relationship):

```
var seeds = [
{
    "word": "Click",
    "definitions": ["Computer", "Mouse", "Tasto", "Pulsante", "Selezionare"]
}, {
    "word": "Galoppo",
    "definitions": ["Cavallo", "Andatura", "Trotto", "Ippica", "Passo"]
}, {
    "word": "Raggio",
    "definitions": ["Sole", "Bicicletta", "Diametro", "Luce", "Laser"]
}, {
.
.
.goes on for 1089 objects
```

This is what I tried:

```
exports.seed = function (knex, Promise) {
var promises = seeds.map(function (seed) {
    return knex('words').insert({
        word: seed.word
    }, 'id').then(function (word_id) {
        var promises = seed.definitions.map(function (definition) {
            return knex('definitions').insert({
                definition: definition
            }, 'id').catch(function (err) {
                if (err.code === 1062)
                    return knex('definitions').select('id').where({
                        definition: definition
                    }).then(function (duplicate) {
                        return knex('definitions_words').insert({
                            definition_id: duplicate[0].id,
                            word_id: word_id
                        });
                    });
            }).then(function (definition_id) {
                return knex('definitions_words').insert({
                    definition_id: definition_id,
                    word_id: word_id
                });
            });
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
});
return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Words are unique in my seeds but definitions may repeat, so I catch the duplication error and grab the id of the duplicate to put that in the junction table. It seems to work fine, the junction table in fact ends up with 1089*5 rows (5445), but I get an error on the cli:

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`mytable`.`definitions_words`,
CONSTRAINT `definitions_words_definition_id_foreign`
FOREIGN KEY (`definition_id`) REFERENCES `definitions` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although we can't see your migrations (and this is a rather old question) what's usually going on with these foreign key restrictions is that you've defined `definition_id` in `words` to reference `definitions.id`. For this reason, you can't create the `word` before the `definition` it references exists.

Without testing it, and bare of error-checking, I'd imagine you using something more like this:

```js
exports.seed = function (knex, Promise) {
  var promises = seeds.map(function (seed) {
    // Check for an existing definition. More recently
    // you can use `whereNotExists` but you always need
    // an id here whatever the case
    return knex('definitions')
      .select('id')
      .where('definition', seed.definition)
      .then(function (definition_id) {
        if (definition_id.length === 1) return definition_id[0]
        return knex('definitions')
          .insert({ definition: definition })
      })
      .then(function (definition_id) {
        // Use the definition once it exists
        return knex('words')
          .insert({ word: seed.word, definition_id: definition_id })
          .then(function (word_id) {
            return { word_id: word_id, definition_id: definition_id }
          });
      })
      .then(function (join_ids) {
        // Finally, update the join table
        return knex('definitions_words')
          .insert({
            definition_id: join_ids.definition_id,
            word_id: join_ids.word_id
          })
      })

  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```